# call_usermodehelper won't execute "&> file" command

Tags: shell, kernel

```
static int sony_get_bt_hostaddr(struct sony_sc *sc)
{
    int ret;

    char * envp[] = { "HOME=/", NULL };

    char * argv[] = { "system/bin/sh", "-c", "su", "'/vendor/bin/btnvtool -x'", "&>", "/sdcard/bthostaddr.txt", NULL };
    
        ret = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
    
        printk("sony_get_bt_hostaddr %x", ret);

        return 0;
}
```

trying to get sh command output via `call_usermodehelper()`, the return value is 0, presumably is the correct result returned but it seems just stopped at `"'/vendor/bin/btnvtool -x'"`, the last part of argv `"&>", "/sdcard/bthostaddr.txt"` does not execute at all, no txt file could be found at `/sdcard/bthostaddr.txt`.

it's no problem at all when i enter the command `system/bin/sh -c su '/vendor/bin/btnvtool -x' &> /sdcard/bthostaddr.txt` in terminal, the file is created with the `btnvtool -x` result in there

(`' '`are required for`/vendor/bin/btnvtool -x` or won't get result in the created file, so i just mimic it in my code).

what's wrong with my code actually?
or is there any alternative way to get the exact output in return instead of just 0/stores in a file?

(ps: the code is running in android environment fyi)

Comment: Why do you write `&>` as one item? This are two separate shell operators.

Comment: @schily i just follow the way written in terminal...so i need to separate it to `"&", ">"`?

Comment: same result separated

Comment: Well, I asked since some shells implement a nonstandard extension for `&>` and you might expect this nonstandard behavior.

Comment: @fei see [Bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism), in particular the "Redirections" section